# Pressing a button within another application in the loop

Tags: c#, loops, button

I have successfully written an application to press a button within another application. Now I am trying to repeat the button presses in a loop and my application hangs, but I don't understand why.

**Context**

I have an application which is very helpful for me, but the person who developed it did not think of everything. At some point within the application a dialog box opens asking for confirmation to replace existing data with uploaded data. I need to click <kbd>OK</kbd> to agree, but the problem is I upload a lot of data to this application and it does not have an "apply to all" checkbox. So I have to click <kbd>OK</kbd> repeatedly. Therefore, I am working on an application which will press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button for me until the dialog stops appearing.

**Code**

Code to click the button once (this works)...

```
private void btnOKloop_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int hwnd=0;
    IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;

    //Get a handle for the Application main window
    hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Desired MessageBox");

    hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");

    //send system message
    if (hwnd != 0)
    {
        SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button Could Not Be Found!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }

}
```

Code to click the button in a loop (this hangs)...

```
private void btnOKloop_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int hwnd=0;
    IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;

    hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Desired MessageBox");

    hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");

    do 
    {
        SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  
    } while (hwnd != 0);
```

Comment: Guys please, someone? I am sure it is very simple, but I had tried a lot of staff and none of it works, the application hangs and that's it. Also I had searched on Internet and used Stackoverflow search, unsuccessful!!!!! PLEASE!!!!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You say that as soon as you press a button to start a loop your application hangs, maybe is because that loop is running in the UI thread? Please be more specific and post the code that is actually giving you issues.

Comment: Your application appears to hang because it is running through the loop, repeatedly calling `SendMessage`. You should perhaps modify your code to run the loop on a different thread, or to send periodic messages based on a timer rather than looping incessantly.

Comment: Oops, then I guess I stuck??? Any help from anyone??? Please I desperately need it, as I fed up pressing enter button!!!

Comment: Do not change your original question. This question has been answered. Please ask a new question.

Comment: This is for cookie clicker isn't it?

Comment: Shawn - Not it is not.  Cybȫʁgϟ37 thank you for your input, I have fixed myself, now will start working on background worker, for now will try to do it myself, later will ask if would not be able to figure out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will never exit:

```
hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Desired MessageBox");

hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");

do 
{
    SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  
} while (hwnd != 0);
```

You've set your `hwnd` variable outside the loop and then loop until the value changes to 0. But since you aren't setting the value within your loop, it will *never* change. You might be able to fix this by simply moving the variable assignment statements within your loop:

```
do 
{
    hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Desired MessageBox");
    if (hwnd != 0) {
        hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
        SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  
    }
} while (hwnd != 0);
```

You might have some trouble with this though.... it might move too quickly, trying to find the next dialog before the dialog has had a chance to open. I suggest you add a small delay and tune it to the appropriate period of time to allow the next window to open:

```
do 
{
    hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Desired MessageBox");
    if (hwnd != 0) {
        hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
        SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); // 250 milliseconds: 0.25 seconds between clicks.
} while (hwnd != 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will certainly try it and will come back with the results, thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much it works!!!! But now I need to figure out, how to add a button to stop a loop, manually, also strange thing happens, the application works, but after few seconds it says my "Loop" application not responding, but it steal works, would you know what causing it? Is it because I am not using background workers??? Thanks

Comment: @o0Lucky0o - If you have additional questions, make sure you've done your due diligence (researched it yourself a bit) and then ask a new question. Asking new questions in comment threads is unhelpful for future visitors.

Comment: Sorry, will take that on board.